# Must every surjective linear transformation become an isomorphism after suitably restricting the domain space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it true that for every vector space linear transformation, say $f:V\rightarrow W$ that is surjective, we can restrict $f$ to a suitable subspace of $V$ to make the restriction an isomorphism.

I know that the restriction to $V/W$ does the job, but how do I identify it with a subspace of $V$. I was also thinking about the infinite dimensional case. Thanks.

Comment: Since it is surjective, take any basis of $W$, and for each element in that basis, pick a preimage. Prove that the span of those preimages is a subspace of $V$ isomorphic to $W$. In the infinite dimensional case, you can't use this argument, since here, we are using the fact that the basis is finite. I don't know if some axiom of choice may help here, though, and I think the answer for infinite dimensional spaces is in the affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you put an inner product on your vector space, then there is an isomorphism between $V/W$ and $W^\perp$. So it can always be done, although there may not be a canonical choice of inner product. Even in infinite dimensions if you have a strong enough axiom of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Taken any basis of $\operatorname{kernel}(f)$, extend this to a basis of $V$, and let $V_0$ be the span of the vectors in the extension. The restriction of $f$ to $V_0$ is an isomorphism.